# Plot scala arrays with jfreechart

Tags: scala, plot, jfreechart

I have 2 scala array and I would like to plot them as an x,y plot.

I have heard that jfreechart is a good choice for plotting in scala.
I think that the right command to plot them is `XYPlot` but how can I use it?

```
  val x = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    val y = x.map(_*2)
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot
```

with python matplotlib I would have just used `plot(x,y)`

Comment: You may want to look at [scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart).

Comment: Scala chart is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put your data into a `DataSet` and then use a `ChartFrame` to display the chart.

```
import org.jfree.chart._
import org.jfree.data.xy._

val x = Array[Double](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
val y = x.map(_*2)
val dataset = new DefaultXYDataset
dataset.addSeries("Series 1",Array(x,y))

val frame = new ChartFrame(
  "Title",
  ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
    "Plot",
    "X Label",
    "Y Label",
    dataset,
    org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,
    false,false,false
  )
)
frame.pack()
frame.setVisible(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by previous comments, there is [scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart), with which you get much more scala-idiomatic usage:

```
import scalax.chart._
import scalax.chart.api._

val xy = for (x <- 1 to 10) yield (x,x*2)

val chart = XYLineChart(xy)

chart.show()
```

There is not yet a DSL like matplotlib/Matlab/Mathematica provide, but contributions are always welcome ;)

The syntax above is, however, the best you can do without a DSL that is focused on quickly plotting some data.

**Note:** There are no automatic conversions for `Array`, which is why the example works with the for loop, all standard Scala collections are supported.